access S3 bucket using IAM roles in nodejs app for local development
I have IAM user who can access S3 buckets (through different policies)
Our app backend is written using Node/Express.
For simple Nodejs local development, I have following configurations to access S3 bucket.
controller.js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

S3 = new AWS.S3({
        accessKeyId: "accessKeyId",
        secretAccessKey: "secretAccessKey",
        region: "region",
        signatureVersion: "v4",
});

const getObject= (key, bucketName) => {
    return S3.getObject({ Bucket: bucketName, Key: key }).promise();
};

getObject("some_key", "some_bucket");

When I run my app, it works and get a specific S3 object back.
My Question: As you can see, I have to hard code accessKey, secretAccessKey currently. Is there any way eg using IAM Role or any other way by which I don't have to expose my accessKey or secretAccesskey (for local development).
One method I know is to keep secrets in .env file but I don't want to go with it.
Pls note, I'm talking about local development of Nodejs, AWS and yet I want to avoid hard coding way of secrets.

Agree that it's best not to explicitly indicate credentials in your code. Store the AWS credentials locally in ~/.aws/credentials or in your environment. See here. Learn how to use credentials profiles e.g. the default profile or another indicated by AWS_PROFILE in your environment.

If you don't specify the credentials then the
AWS SDK will automatically use the local one
Install the AWS CLI  locally and configure it
You can follow this guide Here
Then use your IAM credential to configure the CLI - run this command
aws configure

It stores your credentials in the path:  ~/.aws/credentials
change this
S3 = new AWS.S3({
        accessKeyId: "accessKeyId",
        secretAccessKey: "secretAccessKey",
        region: "region",
        signatureVersion: "v4",
});

to this
const S3 = new AWS.S3({
    region: 'region', 
    signatureVersion: 'v4',
});

If it persists
Confirm your credentials in the files using
cat ~/.aws/credentials
cat ~/.aws/config

the config stores things like the region but the credentials store your

It throws Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1. I ran set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1 still it throws the same error.

@micronyks Verify your credentials , i made some edits to the answer that might help
